# HTML page size, height wrap content

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to set the HTML page size for invoice printing, I want  80mm width and height wrap to content. I tried this:

```
@page {
    size: 80mm 100mm;

}
```

Here I have to mention the height along with the width. I just want to mention the width and height should be wrapped to content. How can I do this?